# Num array to an int: When the length of array is 9, it works fine. But as the length increases to 10, I am not getting the correct val

Tags: java, integer, size

I have the following array:

> int digits[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,1};

I expect the following output of my main function:

> 9876543211

But I get:

> 1286608619

For `digits = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]` I get as expected `987654321`.

I know it is something related to the size of int, can someone point out what changes do I need to make.

```
public class practice
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int digits[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,1};
    int j = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = digits.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      sum = sum + digits[i] * j;
      j = j * 10;
    }
    System.out.print(sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the biggest value an `int` can be? Is it, by chance, exactly 10 digits long? Could it be that you need to switch to `long` (for about 19 digits) or even `BigInteger` (for arbitrarily many digits at the cost of more memory and slower processing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change digit and sum types from int to long